# Can't open a font file using reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I am creating a PDF invoice from an excel sheet, but getting this error:

```
reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFError: Can't open file "Arial.ttf
```

This is the code I'm running:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFont
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', 'Arial.ttf'))
```

Comment: Do you actually have that file?

Comment: no ,can you tell me where to download and where to upload

Comment: @Tomerikoo can you tell me?

Comment: I never used `reportlab` or dealt with fonts. I was just pointing out the obvious...

Comment: ok,no issue,can you tell me some other way to solve my tsask

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar with `reportlab`'s use of fonts. Where and what files it is looking for. Try to check the documentations of the relevant functions